# Creating full_url method in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, absolute-path

I'm trying to make a method to check if the url is an absolute or relative url. I'm calling the method from my view template, but it's raising undefined method error. I believe it's not calling the method, and that's why raising the error, but I'm not sure how to make it work now.

Anything helps, thank you.

> UsersController

```
def url_checker(url)
  /^http/i.match(url) ? url : "http://#{url}"
end
```

> users/show.html.slim

```
span= link_to_if @profile.company_url.present?, @profile.company_url, url_checker(@profile.company_url), target: "_blank"
```

> Error message

[image]

Comment: Move the `url_checker` from `UsersController` to `UsersHelper` and then try it.

Comment: An alternative to Deep's answer, you can add `helper_method :url_checker` to your `UsersController`.

Comment: @Deep, Thank you! It's workig now:)

Comment: @ThomasR.Koll Thank you for the advice!